# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: Operation is not supported in reader account

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read data from the view created in Snowflake and store data to GCS through PySpark.

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "XXX.snowflakecomputing.com",
  "sfUser" : "XXX",
  "sfPassword" : "XXX",
  "sfDatabase" : "DB",
  "sfSchema" : "XXX",
  "sfWarehouse": "DWH"
}

df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  options(**sfOptions) \
  option("query",  "SELECT * FROM JOB_v1").load()

df.show()
```

I am using the following packages:

```
packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0
net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4
```

I can load the data, count the rows, print the schema but when I am trying to write or show the data frame then getting following exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.showString.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
Operation is not supported in reader account.
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:139)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:64)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:491)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:368)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:486)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:237)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:176)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:683)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeQueryInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:242)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeQuery(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:160)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:256)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:254)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:291)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Spark 2.4 is pretty old, do you think you have the correct Spark version?

Comment: I am following the steps given on https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#configuring-the-pyspark-script not sure the Spark version has to do with this as exception seems to be originating from Snowflake.

Comment: Can you check the logs in Snowflake for this error? That can reveal more details. Also: Are the credentials effectively from a reader account?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Unfortunately I can't do that as we are not the actual customers of Snowflake and the DWH is at our vendor's side. Yes, the credentials are from the reader account.

Comment: I'm not sure you shared all the relevant code, but the question says this error happens when you try to "write" with a "reader" account. That might be the desired behavior from the vendor that shared with you this account.

Comment: I am reading the data from Snowflake and writing it to GCS.

Comment: The error "Operation is not supported in reader account" is a Snowflake error. Even though the operation is attempting to write to GCP, something in the process appears to be trying to create a temp table, write data to a temp stage, or something like that on the Snowflake side to process the write operation. You can check in the Snowflake reader account's History tab what the SQL is that's failing. It should help diagnose and if possible avoid that attempted write on the Snowflake reader account.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to consider here:

1. A reader account is intended primarily for querying data shared by the provider of the account. Adding new data to the account and/or updating shared data in the account is not supported - Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html#what-is-restricted-allowed-in-a-reader-account
2. use_copy_unload - If this is FALSE, Snowflake uses the Arrow data format when SELECTing data. If this is set to TRUE, then Snowflake reverts to the old behaviour of using the COPY UNLOAD command to transmit selected data. This parameter is optional. The default value is FALSE.